# UIScrollView inside UICollectionViewCell not scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm setting up a `UICollectionViewCell`like this:

```
    self.background = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.contentView.frame.size.width, self.contentView.frame.size.height)];
    self.background.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.background.scrollEnabled = YES;
    self.background.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;

    // configure image
    self.image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.contentView.frame.size.width, self.background.frame.size.height)];

    [self.background addSubview:self.image];

    // configure title
    self.title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, self.contentView.frame.size.width-10, 70)];
    [self.background addSubview:self.title];

    // configure description
    self.description = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 80, self.contentView.frame.size.width-10, 20)];
    [self.background addSubview:self.description];

    self.textView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.image.frame.size.height+10, self.contentView.frame.size.width, 40)];
    self.textView.delegate = self;
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head></head><body id='foo'>%@</body></html>", @"<p>kbafdj akdjfnadf jhadkfb ij daofhu adofh oj afoduuh oiad fohfd ouhadf dj aodfhj ah adlfk ohad ofladjhfl aojadf oadfh oadhf adfladf adfoadf oadfh aodfh a oadf aodf  afdjladf oad jladfl aodf alf d  adjfladf   adfj aldfkajdfljad aodfj adlfj ad aldjf adlfj al adfjadlfa d adf adf ad pajdf aldjf adkh pfbd fpqehf qehf qepd af pqif phhf q piiqihpsdhvpvqohro pdh wpvhqf lorem ipsum dfkbshbs k bfjsv ohfakdjb </p>"];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    [_textView loadHTMLString:content baseURL:baseURL];
    [self.background addSubview:_textView];

    [self addSubview:self.background];
    [self sendSubviewToBack:self.background];
    [self.background setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.contentView.frame.size.width, 2*self.contentView.frame.size.height)];
```

The `UICollectionView` features fullscreen `UICollectionViewCell`s that scroll horizontally. There's also a `UIGestureRecognizer`on the `UICollectionView`:

```
self.pinchRecognizer =
[[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self                                    action:@selector(closeCell:)];
self.pinchRecognizer.delegate = self;
[_collectionView addGestureRecognizer:self.pinchRecognizer];
```

Now, what doesn't work is the `UIScrollView`. I don't understand what's going wrong, so if anyone could help me out here, that would be swell. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you looked into UIGestureRecognizerDelegate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that I was sending the `UIScrollView` to the back of the `UICollectionViewCell`. Removing `[self sendSubviewToBack:self.background];` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Possible that the UIWebView subview is handling the panning gesture. Try disabling touch interactivity on the webview.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't the problem :(